# Having an issue calling a function within a function in Python

Tags: python, function, object

I'm currently an amateur coder learning Python. I created a Rock, Paper, Scissors program that I exaggerated pretty much to practice calling functions within functions/ object oriented programming.
Issue: I created this program to link different functions together. (The end of one function calls another one). However, after running the program, it reads the first function but doesn't allow the user to continue with the second function, and so on. Can anyone proofread my code to see what the issue is ?

```
from random import randint
def func(n,v):
    if (n==1): 
        print "You chose Rock"
    elif n==2:
        print "You chose Paper"
    elif n==3:
        print "You chose Scissors"
    comp_call(v)

def translate_num(n):
    if n==1:
        print "Rock"
    elif n==2:
        print "Paper"
    elif n==3:
        print "Scissors"

def comp_call(v):
    if v==1: 
        "Computer chose rock"
    elif v==2:
        "Computer chose paper"
    elif v==3:
        "Computer chose scissors"
    check(n,v)

def check(n,v):
    if n==v:
        print "You both chose " + translate_num(n) + " try again!"
        n = int(raw_input())
        v = randint(1,3)
        return func(n,v)
    elif n==1 & v==2:
        print "Paper covers rock. Computer win!"
    elif n==1 & v==3:
        print "Rock beats scissors. You win!"
    elif n==2 & v==1:
        print "Paper covers rock. You win!"
    elif n==2 & v==3:
        print"Scissor beats paper. Computer wins!"
    elif n==3 & v==1:
        print "Rock beats scissors. Computer wins!"
    elif n==3 & v==2:
        print "Scissors beats paper. You win!"

print "Please enter a number: 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors"
n = int(raw_input())
v = randint(1,3)
func(n,v)
```

Comment: use a loop, not recursion.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for checking out my post. Did you mean a for loop or a while loop ? I'm not sure exactly how I would implement that. I used n==v as a base case for the recursion.

Comment: Calling functions withing functions does not make something object oriented. Object oriented programming involves using classes.

Comment: This should probably be a `while True:` loop. When you want to end, use `break`.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for clarifying my confusion.
Thank you for the suggestion I'm going to try to debug my program right now!

Answer (score 0):

In the second function, comp_call, you have no "print"s anywhere.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, I completely missed that one

Answer (score 0):

you cant call them without passing in arguments

Comment: Ah yes thank you. I was thinking I can pass the same arguments from previous functions but in some of them I forgot to carry both arguments (n and v). 
thank you again for your suggestion.